# Cash On Delivery Payment method storewise

Tags: magento-1.9, payment-methods

I want to set Cash On Delivery Payment method storewise so how can it be done?

Is it okay to change in `system.xml`

```
<show_in_default> to make visible in Default Config Mode.

<show_in_website> to make visible in Website Mode.

<show_in_store> to make visible in Store View Mode.
```

Comment: Im not sure what exactly you want to do. Can You explain?

Comment: @KonradSiamro: I've multiple stores, And I want to enable Cash On Delivery Payment method for one store only not for all stores...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done in following way by overriding payment `system.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
   <sections>
        <payment>
            <groups>
                <cashondelivery translate="label">
                    <label>Cash On Delivery Payment</label>
                    <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                    <sort_order>30</sort_order>
                    <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                    <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                    <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                    <fields>
                        <active translate="label">
                            <label>Enabled</label>
                            <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
                            <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_yesno</source_model>
                            <sort_order>1</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        </active>
                        <title translate="label">
                            <label>Title</label>
                            <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                            <sort_order>10</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        </title>
                        <order_status translate="label">
                            <label>New Order Status</label>
                            <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
                            <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_order_status_new</source_model>
                            <sort_order>20</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        </order_status>
                        <allowspecific translate="label">
                            <label>Payment from Applicable Countries</label>
                            <frontend_type>allowspecific</frontend_type>
                            <sort_order>50</sort_order>
                            <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_payment_allspecificcountries</source_model>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        </allowspecific>
                        <specificcountry translate="label">
                            <label>Payment from Specific Countries</label>
                            <frontend_type>multiselect</frontend_type>
                            <sort_order>51</sort_order>
                            <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_country</source_model>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                            <can_be_empty>1</can_be_empty>
                        </specificcountry>
                        <instructions translate="label">
                            <label>Instructions</label>
                            <frontend_type>textarea</frontend_type>
                            <sort_order>62</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        </instructions>
                        <min_order_total translate="label">
                            <label>Minimum Order Total</label>
                            <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                            <sort_order>98</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        </min_order_total>
                        <max_order_total translate="label">
                            <label>Maximum Order Total</label>
                            <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                            <sort_order>99</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        </max_order_total>
                        <sort_order translate="label">
                            <label>Sort Order</label>
                            <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                            <sort_order>100</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        </sort_order>
                    </fields>
                </cashondelivery>
            </groups>
        </payment>
    </sections>
</config>
```

And in module `app/etc/modules/mymodule.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <my_module>
      <active>true</active>
      <codePool>local</codePool>
      <depends>
        <Mage_Payment />
      </depends>
    </my_module>
  </modules>
</config>
```

Since in all stores currency is same so I think it won't be a problem.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think just changing in system.xml will  work. By default you can enable/disable payment method by website wise.

To do it by store wise

you need to override below class

**Mage_Payment_Model_Method_Cashondelivery**

and add below function

```
public function __construct()
{
    $storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getStoreId();
    if($storeId == 1) // add your condition here
    {
        $this->_canUseCheckout = false;
    }
}
```

value of **$this->_canUseCheckout** is used in **Mage_Payment_Model_Method_Abstract** class to check is payment method can used in checkout if you want to disable payment method in backend too you need to **$this->_canUseInternal = false** too